# how to create rest api using node.js express js and oracledb for update database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, oracle11g

i am new to node.js and want to create api for getting data and update that data on frontend,please give me solution for this,i am getting data from this code but unable to update data.I am using react js for frontend.

```
  var express = require("express");
  var app = express();
  var oracledb = require('oracledb');
  var dbconfig= require('./dbconfig')
  (async function () {
  let connection
   try {
      connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: 'dbconfig.user',
      password: 'dbconfig.password',
      connectString: 'dbconfig.connectstring'
      });
     var result = await connection.execute('select * from 
        PROPERTY.app_booklet_challan_detail', []);
     console.log("Successfully connected to Oracle!")
      console.log(result)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("Error: ", err);
      } finally {
     if (connection) {
      try {
       await connection.close()
      } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error when executing the database connection: ", err);
   }
    }
   }
   app.use((req, res, next) => {
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
   res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE')
   next();
   });
   app.get('/list', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send(result);
      next()
  });
   app.put('/list/update', (req, res, next) => {
   let STATUS=res.data
   connection.execute('UPDATE PROPERTY.app_booklet_challan_detail SET STATUS= ? WHERE 
   BOOKLETID= ? ', [STATUS])
    res.send(STATUS)
    next()
   })
   app.listen(3001, function () {
   console.log("Started on PORT 3001");
   })
   })()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little broad to answer with code, but I've written an entire series on this topic: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Note there are links to a GitHub repo with the code from each module.

Once you finish with the series you should be able to take things in the direction that makes the most sense for your project.

Comment: i checked this code,and it gives error [Error: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener] { errorNum: 12541, offset: 0 },i am using listner 3002 in my code.

Comment: What database are you trying to connect to? Are you using the VM I use in the series or your own database?